# This is one of the hardest books in the world to understand

Tags: grammar, adjectives, phrases, infinitives, relative-clauses

That's the original sentence.

> This is one of the hardest books in the world **to understand**.

What do you think the function of "*to understand*" is ?

I think it is connected to a whole noun phrase "*the hardests books*" and

this sentence is the same as

> This is one of the books in the world *that are the hardest to understand*.

Do you agree? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think "book" is incidental and that the infinitive is a complement of **hardest**.

> This book is the hardest to understand.
>
> This book is the hardest to tear in half.
>
> This book is the hardest to part with.
>
> This book is the hardest to translate.

Comment: So, the infinitive is a complement of hardest though it is far away from the adjective.(There is "in the world" between them, but I don't it doesn't matter), right?

Comment: I don't think distance matters there, but that's just an opinion.